# HTML greek letters with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

When converting a ggplot graphics to a plotly graphics with `ggplotly`, I can get some HTML, for example in the title:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

library(mvtnorm)
sims <- rmvnorm(500, mean=c(0,0,0))
dat <- setNames(data.frame(sims), c("x", "y", "z"))
dat$z <- dat$x+dat$y

gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_gradient2(limits=c(-2,2), midpoint=0, low=muted("blue"), high=muted("red")) + 
  ggtitle("<em>hello</em>")

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

The title `<em>hello</em>` appears in italic, as expected.

But when I want a HTML greek letter, that does not work:

```
gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_gradient2(limits=c(-2,2), midpoint=0, low=muted("blue"), high=muted("red")) + 
  ggtitle("&Delta;")

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

How to render `&Delta;` as the expected greek letter ?

I'm using `plotly_4.5.2` and `ggplot2_2.1.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with the [decimal character reference](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html):

```
gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_gradient2(limits=c(-2,2), midpoint=0, low=muted("blue"), high=muted("red")) + 
  ggtitle("&#916;")
ggplotly(gg)
```

According to [this comment on the Github repo](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/733#issuecomment-250000079), *plotly.js recently removed generalized HTML entity decoding"*. I'm not sure to understand, but it could be the explanation.

## Update 2017-08-25

The plotly developers have now removed the html decimal character encoding. As a solution, one can directly enter an UTF-8 character, or use `intToUtf8`:

```
ggtitle("Δ")
ggtitle(intToUtf8(0x0394L))
```

Comment: Good! you answered your own question. I'll delete mine. You can accept your own answer just so others know

Comment: @useR Yes, but one cannot accept an own answer before two days.